# Moving From the US to Canada

Tags: canada, us-citizens

Last month I went to Canada to visit a friend. I fell in love with the place, so much so that we talked about me moving there. I plan to move there for maybe a year, perhaps longer, depending on how things are.

I am able to enter Canada and stay for 180 days. After that, how long do I have to be in the US before being able to re-enter Canada for another 180 days?

Comment: Will you be working? What nationality are you?

Comment: Oh yes of course and I am hispanic from the Dominican Republic

Comment: I am a US citizen

Comment: Have you [seen](http://www.canadavisa.com/moving-to-canada-from-the-u-s.html)

Comment: If you intend to _live_ in Canada, take the time to do it right. If you don't, you will eventually find yourself either refused entry at the border or removed from the country, and it will be a very long time after that before you are able to go back, if ever.

Comment: "oh yes of course" is a response to which question? Whether you'll be working?  Do you realize that Americans who go to Canada as visitors under that 180-day visa-free stay are not allowed to work while they're in the country? To work, you need specific permission, which means entering Canada in a different status.

Comment: If you plan on moving to Canada to work, note that with Trump's election the NAFTA agreement that would allow you to do so is in danger.

Comment: Here's a [useful Wiki](http://www.wikihow.com/Move-to-Canada) on how to make the move to Canada.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to settle down in Canada, you should go through the proper channels and apply for a long-term visa, rather that abusing the visa-free route. Also be aware that you're not allowed to work in Canada on a tourist visa.

If you want to learn which type of Canadian visa to apply for you may ask a separate question detailing your profession and intended length of stay.

Comment: Not quite.  The TN visa is a US visa available to Canadian and Mexican citizens.  I'm not sure how the reciprocal system in Canada works; the Wikipedia article you linked to does not describe it, despite its claims to the contrary.

Comment: @phoog post edited

Comment: Americans and Mexicans in NAFTA positions apply for a Canada work permit, like everyone else, [but the employer gets to skip the Labour Market Impact Assessment](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/special-business.asp), making the work permit application more of a pro forma exercise. NAFTA is less of a benefit in Canada than it is in the US since Canada is already fairly liberal about issuing work permits in general while the US isn't.